# Need to redirect maind domain to index.htm via htaccess but DirectoryIndex not working as expected?

Tags: .htaccess

I am helping a friend out with a simple static html site. I have the entire site working.

However, the index file is index.htm and i want people that type the domain (let's say mydomain.com) to be redirected to that index file, so mydomain.com/index.htm

But adding this to .htaccess doesn't work?

```
AllowOverride All
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on  `DirectoryIndexRedirect`

```
DirectoryIndexRedirect on
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.php
```

This will redirect your domain or home directory to `/index.htm` .

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes an internal server error?

Comment: @Tristan sorry, the error was due to `AllowOveride` directive as its not supported in an htaccess file.